# AspNet Identity: How to change default table names without effects on Role Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity-2

I'm using AspNet IdentitySample project installed from nuget.

after install,i changed the default table names with the following code:

```
   public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        static ApplicationDbContext()
        {
            // Set the database intializer which is run once during application start
            // This seeds the database with admin user credentials and admin role
            Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Users");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");

        }
}
```

when i change AspNet Identity default table names, User.IsInRole("Admin") and [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] always return false and i cant access to the UsersAdmin and RolesAdmin Pages.

Although the default user(admin@example.com) and role("Admin") already exists in the generated tables(Users,Roles and UserRoles).

Is there anything else that should be changed?

**UPDATE:**

this is my ApplicationDbInitializer class :

```
public class ApplicationDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ApplicationDbContext> 
{
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context) {
        InitializeIdentityForEF(context);
        base.Seed(context);
    }

    //Create User=Admin@Admin.com with password=Admin@123456 in the Admin role        
    public static void InitializeIdentityForEF(ApplicationDbContext db) {
        var userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var roleManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
        const string name = "admin@example.com";
        const string password = "Admin@123456";
        const string roleName = "Admin";

        //Create Role Admin if it does not exist
        var role = roleManager.FindByName(roleName);
        if (role == null) {
            role = new IdentityRole(roleName);
            var roleresult = roleManager.Create(role);
        }

        var user = userManager.FindByName(name);
        if (user == null) {
            user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = name, Email = name };
            var result = userManager.Create(user, password);
            result = userManager.SetLockoutEnabled(user.Id, false);
        }

        // Add user admin to Role Admin if not already added
        var rolesForUser = userManager.GetRoles(user.Id);
        if (!rolesForUser.Contains(role.Name)) {
            var result = userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, role.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

thanks for assistance...

Comment: Could you provide the code for `ApplicationDbInitializer` ?

Comment: @ LeftyX: I've updated my post

Comment: I've checked your implementation and it seems absolutely fine. Silly question but I guess you have enabled the migration from Package Manager Console: `enable-migrations` and the database is in place with the data ?

Comment: @LeftyX : yes, migrations in enabled and my Entites are in DomainModel classLibrary, also I added my entities in ApplicationDbContext after the OnModelCreating like this : public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<News> News { get; set; } .......  But i made a new project and befor any work, I change the default table names and the Role problems happened

Comment: I wish I could help but cannot figure out what's wrong. I've recreated pretty much everything you're doing and it works on my side.

Comment: @LeftyX: 3 months ago, I started this project, the main project was working until to weeks ago, Suddenly the problem happened, I added "roleManager module remove" in web.config and it worked again until I opened a new project to provide a better version, in new project this problem is stil and dident solved even with adding "roleManager module remove"

Comment: @LeftyX: special thanks for your try...

Comment: Do you have all the nuGet packages updated? roleManager module remove is old stuff. It was used by the membership provider.

Comment: @LeftyX: I just developed the project and didnt update previuse installed packages, may i can fix this with update one bye one pre installed packages comes with IdentitySample Project?

Comment: You can try and update all the nuget package.